# Sort table view cells by detail number value from Firebase

Tags: ios, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

How do you sort table view cells based on the value in the detail text label?  I have names and scores in Firebase that I'm pulling out and want to show in order of the highest to lowest score.

Currently, I'm retrieving the Firebase names and values, but they are just displayed by alphabetical order of the names in the main text field. I've tried sorting by the score values with `{$0.scoreTotal > $1.scoreTotal}` and ordering the Firebase data with `queryOrdered(byChild: "scoreTotal")`, but neither seems to work.

Here's the table view section of code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellMale", for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    let comp = comps[indexPath.row]
    self.comps.sorted(by: {$0.scoreTotal > $1.scoreTotal})


    let dbRef1 = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Live Scoring Male/\(String(describing: comp.name!))/scoreTotal")

    dbRef1.queryOrdered(byChild: "scoreTotal").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let scoreTotal = snapshot.value as! Double

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = String(scoreTotal)

    })

    cell.textLabel?.text = comp.name

    return cell

}
```

Comment: May I know why you are calling database query in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: @CodeChanger I'm learning so I would definitely appreciate a recommendation on how you would organize this. I only need the Firebase value as the detailTextLabel in the table view cell so I had it there.  Would you load the Firebase values in viewDIdLoad then load the values into each cell after?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is never call any services into `cellForRowAtIndex` and call it when it needed like while we load view use `viewDidLoad()` method for loading any data into that Controller.

so call above method into `viewDidLoad` and regarding sorting your data

**use FireBase sorting like below:**

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: <FIREBASE_URL>).child("topics")
        let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "scores")
        query.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                print(childSnapshot)
            }
        })
```

catch this into Local Array or Dictionary and use it in your TableView with `reloadData()` method.